# Photo app that automatically censors people faces?

Tags: android, photography, privacy, camera

I need to take many photos during a family house being constructed, but I don't want the builder people's faces to be recognizable.

Is there a photo application for Android phones that automatically censors the faces/maybe bodies of humans? So they will not argue about that they don't want to be on the photo, which I fully understand.

Comment: Do you want the software to be a camera app that blurs people's faces, or an app that processes existing photographs?  Do you have a price range?  If you will, please update your question with these details.  Thanks!

Comment: open to any solution, so both ideas would be great! :\